# AJAX request not working GAE

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm following a tut from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkddK0Rd7nA) but I can't get the ajax to work, also I did checked the headers in chromes console, but I didn't see a text/json header as well! Could you please help me with it I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

**main.py**

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    if self.request.get('fmt') == 'json':
        data = {'name' : 'sam', 'age': 25}
        self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/json'
        self.response.write(json.dumps(data))
        return
    self.templateValues = {}
    self.templateValues['title'] = 'AJAX JSON'
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(self.templateValues))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', Main),], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<input type ="button" id="getitbutton" value="click button"/>
<div id= "result">
</div>
```

**js script**

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
function showData(data){
    console.log(data.name);
    $('#result').html(data.name)
}
function handleclick(e){
    $.ajax('/',{
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            fmt: 'json'
        }
        success: showData
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getitbutton').on('click', handleclick);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the current browsers, especially IE which does not send the text/json content type header. So I learned not to depend on the headers.

Instead my solution to this is like this:

The js ajax function:

```
function ajax(url,obj,callback){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(this.readyState==4){
            if(callback){
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("POST",url);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Then on the server side, I read directly from the Request Body (sorry for the Go code, but I think you can also get the Request body from Python runtime?):

```
// read the request body
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(httpRequest.Body)

// parse the json payload
var user struct {
        Email    string
        Password string
}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &user)
```

Hope this helps